# How do I copy and paste a specific range to the next blank value of that range? EG: Copy A4:A12 and paste at F4:F12

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to automate a copy/paste macro. I am trying to copy the values in the range from C4:C12 and paste them at the next blank column in the same range of rows. This is the code I have currently:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim range_to_copy As Range
    Dim range_to_paste As Range

    Set range_to_copy = Application.Range("C4:C12")
    Set range_to_paste = 1 + Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column


        range_to_copy.Copy
        range_to_paste.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I keep getting an object error and I don't understand where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `1 + Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column` returns a number, not a `Range`.

Comment: `Set range_to_paste = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).offset(0,1)`

Comment: @BigBen I think I understand where I went wrong now, that code came from some poor googling.

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you, that worked perfectly.